# Do instruction sets like x86 get updated? If so, how is backwards compatibility guaranteed?

Tags: cpu-architecture, instruction-set

How would an older processor know how to decode new instructions it doesn't know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New instructions use previously-unused opcodes, or other ways to find more "coding space" (e.g. prefixes that didn't previously mean anything for a given opcode).

> How would an older processor know how to decode new instructions it doesn't know about?

It won't.  A binary that wants to work on old CPUs as well as new ones has to either limit itself to a baseline feature set, or detect CPU features at run-time and set function pointers to select versions of a few important functions.  (aka "runtime dispatching".)

x86 has a good mechanism (the `cpuid` instruction) for letting code query CPU features without any kernel support needed.  Some other ISAs need CPU info hard-coded into the OS or detected via I/O accesses so the only viable method is for the kernel to export info to user-space in an OS-specific way.

Or if you're building from source on a machine with a newer CPU and don't care about old CPUs, you can use `gcc -O3 -march=native` to let GCC use all the ISA extensions the current CPU supports, making a binary that will fault on old CPUs.  (e.g. x86 #UD (UnDefined instruction) hardware exception, resulting in the OS delivering a SIGILL or equivalent to the process.)

Or in some cases, a new instruction may decode as something else on old CPUs, e.g. x86 `lzcnt` decodes as `bsr` with an ignored REP prefix on older CPUs, because x86 has basically no unused opcodes left (in 32-bit mode).  Sometimes this "decode as something else" is actually useful as a graceful fallback to allow transparent use of new instructions, notably `pause` = `rep nop` = `nop` on old CPUs that don't know about it.  So code can use it in spin loops without checking CPUID.

`-march=native` is common for servers where you're setting things up to just run on that server, not making a binary to distribute.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times, old processor will have "Undefined Instruction" exception. The instruction is not defined in old CPU.

In more rare cases, the instruction will execute as a different instruction. This happens when then new instruction is encoded via obligatory prefix. As an example, PAUSE is encoded as REP NOP, so it executed as nothing on older CPUs.